# JBoss PowerShell client add module path with space

Tags: java, powershell, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to add a module to a WildFly instance using the JBoss PowerShell client, but it fails when the path to the module contains a space.

I have tried wrapping the path in single and double-quotes to no avail.

---

List of use cases tested:

1. Without quotes
2. Using single-quotes
3. Using double-quotes
4. Escaping the space with a backslash (`\`)
5. Escaping space with backtick (`)
6. Using double-quotes inside a single-quoted command
7. Escaping the inner double-quotes with backtick (`)
8. Escaping inner double-quotes with backslash (`\`)
9. Using double double-quotes (`""`)
10. Escaping inner single quotes with backslash (`\`) in a double-quoted command

---

## Examples

### 1. Without quotes

#### JBoss client command

```bsh
.\jboss-cli.ps1 --connect --command="module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=C:/module directory/sqljdbc42.jar"
```

#### Error message

> The command accepts 1 unnamed argument(s) but received: [add, directory/sqljdbc42.jar]

---

### 2. Using single-quotes

#### JBoss client command

```bsh
.\jboss-cli.ps1 --connect --command="module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources='C:/module directory/sqljdbc42.jar'"
```

#### Error message

> The command accepts 1 unnamed argument(s) but received: [add, directory/sqljdbc42.jar']

---

### 3. Using double-quotes

#### JBoss client command

```bsh
.\jboss-cli.ps1 --connect --command="module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources="C:/module directory/sqljdbc42.jar""
```

#### Error message

> 'directory\sqljdbc42.jar' is assumed to be a command(s) but the commands to execute have been specified by another argument: [module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=C:\module]

---

### 4. Escaping the space with a backslash (`\`)

#### JBoss client command

```bsh
.\jboss-cli.ps1 --connect --command="module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=C:/module\ directory/sqljdbc42.jar
```

#### Error message

> Failed to locate C:\module\ directory\sqljdbc42.jar, if you defined a nonexistent resource on purpose you should use the --allow-nonexistent-resources option

---

### 5. Escaping space with backtick (`)

```bsh
.\jboss-cli.ps1 --connect --command="module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=C:/module` directory/sqljdbc42.jar"
```

#### Error message

> The command accepts 1 unnamed argument(s) but received: [add, directory/sqljdbc42.jar]

---

### 6. Using double-quotes inside a single-quoted command

#### JBoss client command

```bsh
.\jboss-cli.ps1 --connect --command='module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources="C:/module directory/sqljdbc42.jar"'
```

#### Error message

> 'directory/sqljdbc42.jar' is assumed to be a command(s) but the commands to execute have been specified by another argument: [module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=C:/module]

---

### 7. Escaping the inner double-quotes with backtick (`)

#### JBoss client command

```bsh
.\jboss-cli.ps1 --connect --command="module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=`"C:/module directory/sqljdbc42.jar`""
```

#### Error message

> 'directory/sqljdbc42.jar' is assumed to be a command(s) but the commands to execute have been specified by another argument: [module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=C:/module]

---

### 8. Escaping inner double-quotes with backslash (`\`)

#### JBoss client command

```bsh
.\jboss-cli.ps1 --connect --command="module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=\"C:/module directory/sqljdbc42.jar\""
```

#### Error message

> 'directory/sqljdbc42.jar\' is assumed to be a command(s) but the commands to execute have been specified by another argument: [module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=\C:/module]

---

### 9. Using double double-quotes (`""`)

#### JBoss client command

```bsh
.\jboss-cli.ps1 --connect --command="module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=""C:/module directory/sqljdbc42.jar"""
```

#### Error message

> 'directory/sqljdbc42.jar' is assumed to be a command(s) but the commands to execute have been specified by another argument: [module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=C:/module]

---

### 10. Escaping inner single quotes with backslash (`\`) in a double-quoted command

#### JBoss client command

```bsh
.\jboss-cli.ps1 --connect --command="module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=\'C:/module directory/sqljdbc42.jar\'"
```

#### Error message

> The command accepts 1 unnamed argument(s) but received: [add, 'C:/module, directory/sqljdbc42.jar\']

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7

Comment: +1 to escaping the inner quotes : `.\jboss-cli.ps1 --command='echo "foo,echo bar"'` doesn't work, but `.\jboss-cli.ps1 --command='echo \"foo,echo bar\"'` does. Single or double quotes don't seem to matter as long as they aren't the same

Comment: @Aaron The quotes work in general but just not with this specific parameter. They appear to be stripped when the command is parsed. I have added new test results to my original post as per your suggestions.

Comment: Your 8th attempt (escaped inner quotes) is the closest to what I could verify worked, but it uses the same quote for outer and inner quotes which I verified was a source of failure. Mind trying again with different quotes?

Comment: @Aaron You are correct. Single-quotes inside double-quoted command failed but double-quotes inside single-quoted command worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is to escape double-quotes inside a single-quoted command.

```bsh
.\jboss-cli.ps1 --connect --command='module add --name=mssql.jdbc --resources=\"C:/module directory/sqljdbc42.jar\"'
```

Thank you @Aaron for your help.